# How to remove marks from skin?

Tags: personal-care

Is it possible to remove injury or marks naturally without using any cream or gel? While waxing a chunk of skin came out of my arm now its been 3 months but its mark is still there . Is there any way to make my skin as it was? It was light in the beginning when the skin came out then it started started healing and now there is a dark mark and it looks slightly pressed since the skin there is gone.

Comment: Shona, welcome! Please do not post the same question twice, instead [edit] it to add more details if necessary. The [tour] and our [help] will provide more information on how this site works. Looking forward to more of your contributions!

Comment: I accidently created that account and tried to merge but i dont know the profile link of the othe account i dont knw how to open that account too .

Comment: Where on the arm is it? Maybe you can have a tattoo build around it?

Comment: Shona, you can always flag a moderator if you need help.

Comment: Yes its on arm . If it doesnt go then i can think of doing  tattoo .

Comment: What flag do ?? I found it in help centre and tour but there was nothing about it  .

Comment: Is the mark darker or lighter than your normal skin?

Comment: Its darker than the normal skin

Answer (score 3):

This is a minor problem and can easily be remedied in less than half-an-hour.

The tendency of the skin to darken with injury is referred to as "marking."

As long as the skin is **darker** than your normal skin colour it is a relatively easy procedure to lighten the skin pigments using an intense pulsed laser by a dermatologist, skin treatment specialist, or a cosmetic surgeon. The specific wavelength of laser that is used has been used successfully for many years. It is not a new concept. The laser is very superficial and its effect is almost immediate. It is a painless procedure. A short (probably free) consultation visit to the doctor's office will confirm this.

Comment: The skin that is not there can be normal too ??

Comment: This answer is NOT correct and is very unecessary. A dermatologist who does not need (or want to scam your money) will confirm this. Give it time to heal. A visit to a doctor office (like I wrote below) will confirm there's nothing to worry about but if you are, you should seek medical advice, and not online.

Comment: @Shona - The laser that is used for pigmentation is not what is used for sculpting which is a bit trickier (time consuming, longer healing, more expensive, etc.). Normally, a cosmetic surgeon will suggest filling a slight cavity such as a wrinkle or other depression. Your issue may not need anything at all.

Comment: I should take medical advice . Thank you for helping . ☺

Answer (score 0):

In short, no. However there things you can do to help it heal.

- Keep it moisturised.
- Sunlight. Sunlight in moderation will help provide the energy to help it heal. Excessive sunlight is bad for the skin.
- Time. Skin is constantly falling off - heck, inside most dust is human skin, so give it time to heal. We all heal at different speeds.

Despite this, 3 months is a long time though - are you anaemic? Your age is important here as we heal fastest when young. Stop smoking, and stop drinking alcohol as they reduce the oxygen around the body meaning your skin receives less. Don't seek medical advice on the internet though.

If you are really concerned then speak to a nurse / pharmacist.

Comment: Yes a bit anaemic . It makes a difference ?

Comment: Anaemic people don't heal as quickly as others. Just relax, you will notice it 100x more than anyone else.

Comment: I would agree with user3791372's comment. You are way more likely to see it than anyone else. In the past I have had black heads on my FACE and no one else noticed them, but they looked huge to me.

Comment: @a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae Yeah thanks 

Comment: This answer is NOT correct. See a dermatologist who will tell you it is reversible.